# Trying to set multiple :has() selectors for table row

Tags: css, html-table, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a table with nested products.
I am using the WooCommerce plugin, so I can't change the HTML markup.

[image: wrong nested style]

As you can see, this works fine with the next table row, for the product that belongs to the one above it. But it does not work for the ones after that. I don't want them to have a border bottom, so it looks like 1 table row. 
It's using `tc-container-table-product` for the main product and `tc-associated-table-product` for the ones that belong to the main product.

I am using (SCSS with Tailwind CSS), code:

```
tr.tc-container-table-product {
            @apply mb-0;

            + tr:not(.tc-associated-table-product) {
                @apply mt-4;
            }

            &:has(+ .tc-associated-table-product) {
                @apply mb-0 !border-b-0 rounded-bl-none rounded-br-none;
            }

            &:has(+ .tc-associated-table-product):has(+ .tc-associated-table-product) {
                @apply mb-0 !border-b-0 rounded-bl-none rounded-br-none;
            }
        }
```

The table HTML is:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-container-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-associated-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-container-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-associated-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-associated-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item tm-epo-cart-row-product-noepo tc-associated-table-product">
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: _"As you can see, this works fine with the next table row, for the product that belongs to the one above it. But it does not work for the ones after that."_ It's not clear what isn't working correctly. The last three subproducts appear to be formatted the same way. Isn't that what you want? Also, please [don't post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: The reason I posted the table as an image is that the table is pretty large if I paste the code here. But i deleted the inside cells and added the code.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you mean by "But it does not work for the ones after that." What is wrong? How do you expect it to look?